# Google Update on windows uploading unusual amount of data

Tags: windows-xp, google-updates

I have a network monitor tool which logs all network activity, today a program called Google Update downloaded 245.34MB and uploaded 1.19GB of data.

The downloading seems like normal activity, but the uploading seems unusual.

I cannot find much on google about this, do you know what it could be?
The only google program I have on my laptop is Google Chrome which I rarely use.

I am running windows XP with Malewarebytes and Kaspersky Internet security.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: @techie007 Wireshark is not useful now as the 1.19GB has already been uploaded, I am very curious as to where it went and what data of mine it was.